# How should iiformat the post data of my forged request with protobuf encoding?

Tags: android, post, encoding, protocol-buffers

I have this post data (Already decoded using a fiddler addon), for an API where you login.

[image: Post request num 1]

I'd like to know how to craft a post request using rawdata, using that post data, and the API I got it from, I also have this one:

```
1 {
  1: "9a8d2f0ce77a4e248bb71fefcb557637"
  2: "96ab690ea118ef2d"
}
2: "\003\000\227\177m\204\v\355\001\031\001\205&d\213[\351\021\2552\352\323\r\347dId\270\253~G\r\340\310%\352^dF\350u\037\2543\317W0\332\264MD*\311\234\246\354\272\254\350apy\376\023.#]\236\035M5\346\270!\3217IZ\363\254\232\203\017\035f!,\267\330\217a:p\331|oM\3565\263\277\232\026c\246\023\336=G\030_\221\023\336\316\0321y\207\222B&\212\365\004\213\336\005\234%\t\262\234\025\233\022\0067Z\321y{=,\320Dx\3227\333\312f&\241\202\177\354\370FB\263q#\273\233i\376Y\243\334\370\244I\362\223\204\241o\002\306u\246+\270\a\276]\t`\230.\214.\370\234]q\301g\315\201\310\250\032R\037{0\320;~-[\365\302\211\224\256yoM\032\203\305\266J\3507CX\243\323\272\206<\343\030N\253\037\370v"
3 {
  1 {
    1 {
      1: "zo\204\366\256Z<\324\000\000\000\000\000\000\003\300"
      2 {
        2: 490000
      }
    }
  }
}
101 {
  1: "stackuser"
  2: "stackpassword"
  3: "******************************************"
}
```